# Test suites for the implementation of Python?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have implemented a subset of Python, and I need to find some test suites  that are used to testing the implementation of Python (yeah, the language itself), something like the test suites used by SpiderMonkey to test the implementation of Javascript, so I am expecting some authoritative, or open sourced that are widely (or actually) used ones....

Comment: When I wrote my implementation of `python` I used `python` to check it. The way I did it was, I wrote a simple `python` program that would test a unit of functionality, and made sure that the output of the script through `python` and my implementation are the same.

Comment: @Doboy Yeah, my bad... I used the same way for the current experimentation. I should have said that I am expecting some authoritative source of test suites (I have modified the questions a little bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you download the CPython source from http://hg.python.org/cpython/, you'll find a massive suite of tests in `Lib/tests`.  These might be of some use.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder and pointer! I was just about to find the one in PyPy :)

Comment: The tests are also included in all of the source release tarballs of Python here: http://python.org/download/

Comment: Is it possible to install the test suite so you can run the tests from the installed interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run the CPython test suite inside the python interpreter.

You should have the test package present in your python installation located into the file `PREFIX/lib/pythonX.Y/test/__init__.py` or you can find it using the command above:

```sh
$ ls -1F $(python -c 'import test; import os; print(test.__file__)')
```

In order to run the test suite, you just have to type:

```
>>> from test import autotest
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/devguide/runtests.html